# getSimSerialNumber() return null inside BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

I have a big problem I want to detect if the SIM card has been changed after BOOT_COMPLETED for BroadcastReceiver 
I'm writing this on my manifest

```
        <receiver android:name="startMobBroacastReciver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and the permissions is

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

and here is my code

```
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    if("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction()))
    {

          tm=(TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            tel_num= (GsmCellLocation) tm.getCellLocation();
           prefs=context.getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0);
           Log.i("SIM", " "+tel_num.getCid()+" "+tel_num.getLac()+" "+tm.getSimSerialNumber());
           sim_serial_number=prefs.getString("SIM_serial", "null");

 Toast.makeText(context, "add "+tm.getSimSerialNumber(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

by the way tel_num.getCid() and tel_num.getLac() return values but tm.getSimSerialNumber() return null ,and this is what will drive me crazy :(
any help please

Comment: When you read [the documentation for `getSimSerialNumber()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimSerialNumber()), what did you learn?

Comment: do you mean that my SIM serial number is unavailable.but l test to write the getSimSerialNumber() in the activity and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Set a delay up to 1 min before getting data from sim card. It is necessary to initialize the card.